# How to run C++ code to interact with GPIO with Apache Webserver on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, apache, webserver, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm new to Raspberry Pi.

I want to run some c++ code (for GPIO controls) on apache webserver on my RPi. I've tried creating a .php file and opening it with browser, it was successful. It was a basic LED function and turned it on.

Can I do it with C++ ?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to do this in C++? Yes/no questions aren't quite good for SO.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there are some libraries you can use to control the GPIO, but I prefer writing directly to /sys/...

In bash you can do it like this:

```
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
```

And finally to clean it up

```
echo "17" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

You can yust "translate" this to C++ using e.g. ofstream:

```
//Set pin direction
std::ofstream out("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction");
out<<"out";
out.close();

//Set pin value
out.open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value");
out<<"1";
out.close();

//Cleanup
out.open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport");
out<<"17";
out.close();
```